# Why do I get a "Hive support is required" error when creating table?

Tags: hive, pyspark, cloudera

Using pyspark within Cloudera, I create a dataframe using 'hiveContext'.Then I am trying to get the dataframe into an sql table using hive.

Here is my code for doing this:

```
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext
hiveContext = HiveContext(SpContext)

from pyspark.sql.types import StructType

schema = StructType.fromJson({'fields': [{'metadata': {},
   'name': 'Date','nullable': True,'type': 'string'},
  {'metadata': {}, 'name': 'Time', 'nullable': True, 'type': 'string'},
  {'metadata': {}, 'name': 'Global_active_power', 'nullable': True, 'type': 'integer'},
  {'metadata': {}, 'name': 'Global_reactive_power', 'nullable': True, 'type': 'string'},
  {'metadata': {},'name': 'Voltage','nullable': True,'type': 'integer'},
  {'metadata': {}, 'name': 'Global_intensity', 'nullable': True, 'type': 'integer'},
  {'metadata': {}, 'name': 'Sub_metering_1', 'nullable': True, 'type': 'string'},
  {'metadata': {}, 'name': 'Sub_metering_2', 'nullable': True, 'type': 'integer'},
  {'metadata': {}, 'name': 'Sub_metering_3', 'nullable': True, 'type': 'string'},
  ],
 'type': 'struct'})

power_cons_hive = power_cons

power_cons_hive_df=hiveContext.createDataFrame(power_cons_hive, schema)
```

Then I register a table:

```
power_cons_hive_df.registerTempTable("mytempTable")
```

Finally, when I do the following code:

```
hiveContext.sql("CREATE TABLE power_consumption STORED AS ORC AS SELECT * FROM mytempTable")
```

I get this error (I am showing the initial block of error since there is a lot):

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o31.sql.
: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Hive support is required to use CREATE Hive TABLE AS SELECT;;
CreateTable CatalogTable(
    Table: `power_consumption`
    Created: Fri Jun 09 10:12:55 PDT 2017
    Last Access: Wed Dec 31 15:59:59 PST 1969
    Type: MANAGED
    Provider: hive
    Storage(InputFormat: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat, OutputFormat: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcOutputFormat, Serde: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcSerde)), ErrorIfExists
   +- Project [Sub_metering_1#141, Sub_metering_3#143]
      +- SubqueryAlias mytemptable, `mytempTable`
         +- Project [Sub_metering_1#141, Sub_metering_3#143]
            +- Project [Sub_metering_1#141, Sub_metering_3#143]
               +- Project [Sub_metering_1#141, Sub_metering_3#143]
                  +- Project [Date#135, Time#136, Global_reactive_power#138, Sub_metering_1#141, Sub_metering_3#143]
                     +- Project [Date#135, Time#136, Global_reactive_power#138, Sub_metering_1#141, Sub_metering_3#143]
                        +- LogicalRDD [Date#135, Time#136, Global_active_power#137, Global_reactive_power#138, Voltage#139, Global_intensity#140, Sub_metering_1#141, Sub_metering_2#142, Sub_metering_3#143]
```

I am not sure why this is the case as I believe my code is correct thus far and Hive has been started and has 'good health' status in Cloudera manager.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It's a Spark configuration problem, not Hive

Comment: @cricket_007 is it a Spark configuration problem because of the 'Py4JJavaError' ? When I interact with  text or .csv files with HDFS and Pyspark there are no complaints. Only with Hive, so still not sure what further configuration is required.

Comment: Hive support needs to be enabled, as the error says. CSV and HDFS files are not Hive tables. http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.3/sql-programming-guide.html#hive-tables

Comment: @cricket_007.....it says " Hive support is enabled by adding the -Phive and -Phive-thriftserver flags to Spark’s build" ........I am assuming I need to re-build  pyspark using these flags. Can you confirm?

Comment: Yes, rebuild all of Spark, not just PySpark. But I would hope that you are using CDH and not a manual installation of Cloudera Manager, and that should all be configured for you already

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try add option `--conf spark.sql.catalogImplementation=hive` to spark-submit.